# How to get smooth shading?

Tags: opengl, xtk

Using [XTK](https://github.com/xtk/X#readme), I tried to load an STL file. The shading is NOT smooth. What all modifications I need to do to get smooth shading?

Comment: So what did you actually do? Any relevant code you could share with use? Normals are set up properly?

Comment: My sample .STL file have the information as follows.

Comment: `code`facet normal 0.468282 -0.863498 -0.187306
    outer loop
      vertex 0.907128 0.646165 0.795193
      vertex 1.655401 1.111567 0.520398
      vertex 0.766146 0.680483 0.284519
    endloop
  endfacet `code`

I know how to calculate smooth normals from faceset and vertex information. But i am wondering whether XTK library have any property to give SMOOTH shading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XTK doesn't re-calculate the normals (yet). Since the .STL only has face normals and no vertex normals, it won't be smooth

you can convert the model to a .vtk file which supports vertex normals.

also, you are welcome to contribute the normals calculation code :) for freesurfer meshes, the normals get recalculated so all the pieces should be there